# Scrollleft function changing css buggy [Edge & Firefox]

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

Building a website where I have to update the css "Left:" position by javascript.
But in firefox and Edge it stutters and doesn't update smooth.

```
$(function() {      
  $('#scroller').scroll(function(){    

    $('.main-titlebar, .main-tabsbar, .main-functionbar').css({
        'left': $(this).scrollLeft()    
    });          
  });
});
```

This is the way I update the css . But it seems there is a delay or something in the scroll event so I tryed the following:

```
function scollPos() {
    var div = document.getElementById("scroller").scrollLeft;
    document.getElementById("strech").innerHTML = div;            
    document.getElementById("titlebar").style.left = div + "px";
}
```

Only this is exactly the same. (was hoping this would be faster). How can I make it smooth in all browsers?

The site: http://dev.logic4.nl/test/

Gif animation chrome: http://dev.logic4.nl/test/chrome.gif

Gif animation Edge: http://dev.logic4.nl/test/edge.gif

Gif animation Firefox: http://dev.logic4.nl/test/firefox.gif

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: nope, there is no (good) solution. the problem was that the scrollbar was updating and the size of the window. 

So the only solution is body{overflow: hidden}

Comment: Any solutions ? I am facing the same issue now in 2020 also. https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/bzuasLcz/3/